# How do Limit the values for some of these shopping cart items?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to limit the amount of quantities that users can add to their cart but I cannot seem to get things to work.

This is the link to the sandbox I am coding into https://codesandbox.io/s/working-forked-game-save-technical-prototype-forked-0tnxy3

The only thing I am expecting is that when you press the plus or minus button certain items only allow one to be added to the total

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend checking out [mcve]. Your question is likely to be closed without providing the minimal code needed to duplicate the problem

Comment: Your link isn't working; that's why it recommended to create a Stack Snippet directly in your post.